# Best practice for signaling that a method is deprecated?

Tags: java, deprecated

I have a method in one of my classes that I don't want it to be used any more. Basically it breaks encapsulation, and I now have better methods I want to be used instead.

What's the best practice for signaling that a method is deprecated?

Comment: What about removing it? Unless you're developing an API used by third parties for example.

Comment: you can use @Deprecated annotation for this

Comment: @sp00m There's a little old code still using this method, but I want to make it clear it's not to be used anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an @Deprecated annotation to that method and tell witch other classes to use in javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Mark using [Deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation.